# How to create tar-ed npm modules

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, tar

I am using https://github.com/allegro/grunt-maven-plugin for building my Java + Angular JS application, and I dont want to download node modules everytime I build this.

As per note on https://github.com/allegro/grunt-maven-plugin, it says use tar-ed node_modules instead of running npm install during each build.

Now how to create **tar-ed node_modules** ? I am guessing, its somekind of zipping the directory but not exactly sure. Is it possible through tools like winzip, 7zip ? Or Do I need to use one more node module to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I did not went into the details of 7zip. With 7zip we can create tar files of folders.

**Update:** But the output tar file is corrupted, now checking why it corrupted the tar file.

**Update** Run 7zip as an administrator and it opens the tar file normally. I think I am good now.

If you are using Unix then use `tar` to create single archive containing all files., Refer: https://github.com/allegro/grunt-maven-plugin/issues/90

Answer (score 0):

Reading https://github.com/allegro/grunt-maven-plugin I understand that you don't need to make a tar of your modules.

The important point is that the offline workflow is used if there exists a folder named "target-grunt" with a folder named "node_modules" inside of it.

So you could just try to copy you actual node_modules folder to a new folder called "target-grunt".

Comment: we want to do this as a part of CI (continuous integration) build, where we don't have option of manual copy since target-grunt folder is also created at the build time. So at the time of build, tar-ed node_modules should be extracted to target-grunt folder.